# How many I use Wildcards while Searching for Instance's Names in Oracle Fusion Middleware?

Tags: weblogic, oracle-fusion-middleware

[image]

I would like to be able to use a wildcard in the "name" field here. Is this possible?

Comment: Most of the Oracle search capabilities I have seen allow wildcards... have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, using the * did not work in the name field.

Comment: Did you try % instead of *